# Angularjs smart-table not sorting $index table cells

Tags: angularjs, grid, smart-table

I have a problem withe the Smart Table AngularJS Sorting, I implemented this on my table as:

The initialized app:

```
angular.module('myproyApp', ['smart-table'])
```

The controller side:

```
$scope.dataList = []; //any json collection with: id, name and description
```

The view side with st-table directive:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" st-table="dataRows" st-safe-src="dataList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><span class="glyphicon"></span>Q</th>
      <th st-sort="name">Name</th>
      <th st-sort="descripcion">Description</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in dataRows">
      <td class="col-md-1">{{$index + 1}}</td>
      <td class="col-md-4">{{row.name}}</td>
      <td class="col-md-4">{{row.description}}</td>
      <td><a href="#anyAction{{row.id}}">Change</a></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

On click the sorting header's cells the table is sorting, but the sorting isn't working for the $index cells. Please if you have any think to include the $index cells to sort. I want not to use the indexes on dataList $scope values, I need that this index will be include only on table view.

Answer (score 1):

Track by is used to link your data with the DOM generation made by ng-repeat. When you add track by you tell angular to generate a single DOM element per data object in the given collection. Because $index has to do with the DOM there is no way to have it relate to a particular data entry. [Here's a more detailed explanation.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm)

If you *really* want to do it without touching your dataList, you could call indexOf in your table:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in dataList | orderBy:sortField">
    <td class="col-md-1">{{dataRows.indexOf(row)}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-4">{{row.name}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-4">{{row.description}}</td>
    <td><a href="#anyAction{{row.id}}">Change</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Where there is a scoped variable called `sortField` which is a string that is the name of the field you wish to sort by. I implemented a similar thing in this plunker, using the smart-tables module. http://plnkr.co/edit/AF90dQ

I would advise against this because it quickly becomes expensive for large arrays, and runs into problems if your entries aren't unique.

Comment: Thank you, the `dataRows.indexOf(row)` efectively display the index, but the smart-table sorting is not working with this, the indexes still remain static.

Comment: I'm not familiar with smart-table sorting but you can use the built-in angular feature | orderBy:'name'. I will update my example

Comment: The required functionality is that allow click on header column and sort, this functionality is success excpet for the first column, this is static.